# select the next date based on a specified date SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a date field in, this date field is called [agreement date], and is a date that is created when am agreement is made to make a payment.  I’m attempting to work out when the next payment is due based on the day of the month.

For example if the Agreement Date is 21-Jan-2014 then the next payment is going to be the 21-June-2014. This is the part I am stuck on, how do I get it to ignore the previous months and simply check the next due date?

Comment: This really isn't clear at all right now. How do 21/01/2014 and 12/06/2014 relate to each other? What calculation is being done to go from one to the other? Where does the 21/01/2014 date even come from? Is that a column in your table, hard-coded?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Sorry, tried to make a bit clearer.

Comment: How often are payments due? Monthly? Quarterly? Every X months (where X isn't a common payment schedule like 3, 6, 9 or 12)?

Comment: So you're looking for the next date, starting today, that has the same "day of month" value as the field "agreement date"?

Comment: @hvd exactly what I am after

Comment: @Gavlaaa can you post your table structure? That help to understand the problem statement and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  [agreement date],
  CASE
  WHEN [payment date this month] >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  THEN [payment date this month]
  ELSE [payment date next month]
  END AS [payment date]
FROM (
  SELECT
    [agreement date],
    DATEADD(
      MONTH,
      DATEDIFF(MONTH, [agreement date], GETDATE()),
      [agreement date]) AS [payment date this month],
    DATEADD(
      MONTH,
      DATEDIFF(MONTH, [agreement date], GETDATE()) + 1,
      [agreement date]) AS [payment date next month]
) AS sub
```

`DATEDIFF(MONTH, x, y)` completely ignores the day-of-month of both `x` and `y`. If `x` is somewhere in January, and `y` is somewhere in February, then `DATEDIFF(MONTH, x, y)` is one, even if the difference is only a single day.

Therefore, you can use `DATEDIFF(MONTH, [agreement date], GETDATE())` to get the number of months to add that would make sure you get this month's payment date. And add one to get next month's payment date.

After that, it's a simple matter of comparing `[payment date this month]` to `GETDATE()` to determine whether that one has passed yet.

Comment: I get a msg error? Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'sub'. ?

Comment: @Gavlaaa Can you show the exact SQL that you tried? You will need to have tweaked my answer slightly to get it to work for you, and that slight tweaking can easily go wrong.

Comment: Would it be difficult to switch this to a weekly version??

Comment: @Gavlaaa Both `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` do support a `WEEK` option, so you could use that. Their definition of "week" may or may not agree with yours (the first day of the week, particularly), but since my answer already checks both the current month and next month (current week and next week after the change), it shouldn't affect you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to do it, but this should work for payments that are due monthly:

```
SELECT [agreement date], 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, [agreement date]) > 28 THEN 
    CONVERT(DATE, CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '/28', 111) 
ELSE 
    CONVERT(DATE, CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, [agreement date]) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 111) 
END AS [Next payment due date]
FROM yourTable
```

Note that it will generate a payment due date on the 28th of the month if the agreement date's day is past then, to account for any potential issues with invalid dates (like the 31st of February).

Comment: This may return a day before today, for example if the agreement date was on the 15th of a month, and today is the 20th.

Comment: @hvd You're right, I only did minimal testing on it. Could solve that with another CASE statement, but then it gets pretty messy. I'm wondering if there's a better way to generate the date from parts.